# 400 Error when trying to Export Data to Google Sheets

Tags: python, dataframe, google-sheets-api, http-status-code-400

Using these functions to take the data from the first sheet and then take specific rows and columns to generate a report. When trying to generate the report on a seperate blank sheet called 'ReportList' I get back a 400 error when I know the credentials.json file is correct since I also tried reauthenticating. I also have two credential files for the different authentication scopes.

```py
def get_google_sheet(spreadsheet_id, range_name):
    # Retrieve sheet data using OAuth credentials and Google Python API.

    global scopes
    global gsheet

    scopes = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets']
    # Setup the Sheets API
    store = file.Storage('credentials1.json')
    creds = store.get()
    if not creds or creds.invalid:
        flow = client.flow_from_clientsecrets('client_secret.json', scopes)
        creds = tools.run_flow(flow, store)
    service = build('sheets', 'v4', http=creds.authorize(Http()))

    # Call the Sheets API
    gsheet = service.spreadsheets().values().get(spreadsheetId=spreadsheet_id, range=range_name).execute()

    return gsheet
```

```
def gsheet2df(gsheet):
    # Converts Google sheet data to a Pandas DataFrame.

    header = gsheet.get('values', [])[0]   # Assumes first line is header!
    values = gsheet.get('values', [])[1:]  # Everything else is data.
    #header = values[0]
    if not values:
        print('No data found.')
    else:
        df = pd.DataFrame.from_records(values)
        df.columns = header

        return df
```

```py
def Export_Data_To_Sheets():


    store = file.Storage('credentials.json')
    creds = store.get()
    if not creds or creds.invalid:
        flow = client.flow_from_clientsecrets('client_secret.json', scopes)
        creds = tools.run_flow(flow, store)
    service = build('sheets', 'v4', http=creds.authorize(Http()))

    RANGE_AND_SHEET = "ReportList!A1:E500"
    response_date = service.spreadsheets().values().update(
        spreadsheetId=SPREADSHEET_ID,
        valueInputOption='RAW',
        range=RANGE_AND_SHEET,
        body=dict(
            majorDimension='ROWS',
            values=df.T.reset_index().T.values.tolist())
    ).execute()
    print('Sheet successfully Updated')
```

When I use just the range without identifying the sheet it works no problem. With the range and sheet I get this error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/adaniel/PycharmProjects/EmailAutomation/venv/AutoEmailScript/test.py", line 126, in <module>
    Export_Data_To_Sheets()
  File "/Users/adaniel/PycharmProjects/EmailAutomation/venv/AutoEmailScript/test.py", line 68, in Export_Data_To_Sheets
    response_date = service.spreadsheets().values().update(
  File "/Users/adaniels/PycharmProjects/EmailAutomation/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/googleapiclient/_helpers.py", line 130, in positional_wrapper
    return wrapped(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/adaniels/PycharmProjects/EmailAutomation/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/googleapiclient/http.py", line 840, in execute
    raise HttpError(resp, content, uri=self.uri)
googleapiclient.errors.HttpError: <HttpError 400 when requesting https://sheets.googleapis.com/v4/spreadsheets/*******yAABhNJvARr9BzsVLvCYSfpcvQAmpWESL-DJI/values/%28%27ReportList%21%27%2C%20%27A1%3AE500%27%29?valueInputOption=RAW&alt=json returned "Invalid JSON payload received. Unexpected token.
House", "10/19/19", NaN, NaN, NaN], ["Co
                    ^">
```

Comment: Have you tried to follow the [quickstart](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/quickstart/python) for authentication?

Comment: @ziganotschka I have not tried the quickstart, but If I change the range back to the original range for the 3rd function Export_Data_To_Sheets(): then the script will work without any errors. But it will post and overwrite the information on the first sheet, which is what I don't want. I can take parts of quickstart and implement it into my code though.

Answer (score 0):

### The problem is the syntax of the [A1Notation](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/guides/concepts#a1_notation)

The `A1 notation` requires a `!` between the sheet name and the range, so:

`ReportList!A1:E500`

instead of

`ReportListA1:E500`.

The correct syntax of a request to contains both value input option and the values nested into the request body:

```
    response_date = service.spreadsheets().values().update(
        spreadsheetId=SPREADSHEET_ID,
        valueInputOption='RAW',
        range=RANGE_AND_SHEET,
        body=#your values here
    ).execute()
```

Mind that for spreadsheets.values.update opposed to spreadsheets.values.batchUpdate you cannot specify the major dimension.

Comment: The original code has ReportList!A1:E500, I'm not sure why there no ! in the code above. With ReportList!A1:E500 I still recieve the error.

Comment: If the error is not related to the `A1` syntax or to a wrong misspelling of the sheetname / case sensitivity, then I do not see why it should work without the sheetname specification but not with it. If the error is not related to the sheetname, it must be related to the syntax of the request, see my updated answer.